# redefinition of a form in C++builder 10.1

Tags: c++, c++builder

I was writing a code for my app and now I can't fix the mess I made and I don't know what's exactly going on

IDE : C++builder 10.1 Berlin (FMX)

error1:

```
[bccaarm Error] texts.cpp(12): redefinition of 'Form4'
texts.cpp(12): previous definition is here
```

error2:

```
[bccaarm Error] texts.cpp(14): redefinition of 'TForm4'
texts.cpp(14):  previous definition is here
```

texts.cpp:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <fmx.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "texts.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"


TForm4 *Form4;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm4::TForm4(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

texts.h:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef textsH
#define textsH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Forms.hpp>
#include <FMX.Controls.Presentation.hpp>
#include <FMX.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <FMX.Types.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm4 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TLabel *erremptb;
    TLabel *errnofloat;
    TLabel *errjustpos;
    TLabel *errnoneg;
    TLabel *errinp2;
    TLabel *errinp1;
private:    // User declarations
public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm4(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm4 *Form4;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

if you need more information just tell it to me and I will be very happy if you help me to solve it

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you have shown. There is no redefinition occurring.

Comment: My guess is that you are including the `texts.cpp` twice somewhere. To check for that add `#ifndef textsCPP #define textsCPP ... #endif` statements to it (just like in the `texts.h`) and if compiled then it is the case. My bet is that you are including it in another form somewhere ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line at texts.cpp

```
TForm4 *Form4;
```

is a redefinition of `Form4`. The first definition is by the end of the previously included texts.h

```
extern PACKAGE TForm4 *Form4;
```

Comment: No, that isn't a redefinition. There is only one definition, in texts.cpp. The other is merely an extern declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It was an IDE bug I delete that form and do sth else to solve problem
before I delete that I comment my texts.cpp file and compile that and after that I uncomment it and code run but after that It don't run any more with my trick so I use Another way to solve my problem . 
thanks for your tries but it was an stupid Radstudio bug